# Let $f$ be a differentiable function satisfying $\log_2(f(3x))=x+\log_2(3f(x))\;\forall x\in\mathbb R$ and $f'(0)=1$. Find the value of $[f(3)]$.

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, contest-math

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function satisfying $\log_2(f(3x))=x+\log_2(3f(x))\;\forall x\in\mathbb R$ and $f'(0)=1$. Find the value of $[f(3)]$, where $[k]$ denotes greatest integer less than or equal to $k$.

**Solution:**

$\log_2(f(3x))=x+\log_2(3f(x))$

$\frac{f(3x)}{3f(x)}=2^x$

$\frac{f(x)}{3f(\frac x3)}\cdot\frac{f(\frac x3)}{3f(\frac x{3^2})}\cdot\frac{f(\frac x{3^2})}{3f(\frac x{3^3})}\cdot\cdot\cdot\frac{f(\frac x{3^{n-1}})}{3f(\frac x{3^n})}=2^{\frac x3}\cdot2^{\frac x{3^2}}\cdot\cdot\cdot2^{\frac x{3^n}}$

$\frac{f(x)}{3^n\cdot f(\frac x{3^n})}=2^{\left(\frac x3+\frac x{3^2}+...+\frac x{3^n}\right)}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x)\cdot\frac x{3^n}}{x\cdot f(\frac x{3^n})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\left(\frac x3+\frac x{3^2}+...+\frac x{3^n}\right)}$

$\frac{f(x)}{x\cdot f'(0)}=2^{\left(\frac {\frac x3}{1-\frac13}\right)}$

$f(x)=x\cdot2^{\frac x2}$

$\therefore f(3)=3\cdot2^{\frac32}=6√2≈8.4$

$\implies[f(3)]=8$

**My doubt:**

They seem to have written $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(\frac x{3^n})}{\frac x{3^n}}=f'(0)$

I don't understand this step.

**My Attempt:**

$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$

Replacing $h$ by $\frac x{3^n}$

$f'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(\frac x{3^n})-f(0)}{\frac x{3^n}}$

I don't think $f(0)$ is zero because that's not in the range.

Comment: May I know the source of the question?

Comment: @Sahaj, a friend gave it to me. I'll ask him tomorrow and will update here.

Comment: @Sahaj the question is taken from Bansal coaching institute's Rank Booster course.

Comment: Oh I am familiar of that name here in India! Never thought functional equations formed a part of IIT JEE courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of absence of Such a function for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Assume A differentiable function $f(x)$ such that $\log_2(f(3x))=x+\log_2(3f(x))$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$,

Given $f'(0)=1$

Noticing the domain of This functional equation, $f(x)\neq 0$   $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

taking Antilogarithm with base $2$ on both sides of functional equation

It follows

$f(3x)=2^x\cdot3f(x) \tag 1$

As the function $f(x)$ is differentiable ,

differentiate equation $1$ on both sides

$3f'(3x)=2^x\ln2(3f(x)) +2^x\cdot3f'(x) \tag 2$

Substituting $x=0$ in equation $2$

$3f'(0)=\ln2\cdot(3f(0)) +3f'(0) \tag 3$

substituting $f'(0)=1$ in equation $3$

it follows

$1=\ln2\cdot f(0)+1$

yielding

$f(0)=0$

But this contradicts the statement $f(x)\neq0$ which was a direct consequence of domain of functional equation, Hence by contradiction, Such function does not exist $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think you want to write 'yielding $f(0)=0$'.

Comment: So, you are suggesting the question is wrong?

Comment: Any suggestions regarding how to make the question valid?

Comment: Maybe we can say the functional equation holds $\forall x\in\mathbb R-\{0\}$ and for $x=0, f(x)=0$

Comment: @aarbee, Regarding your first comment, Yes it  was a typo, Now regarding the second comment, Yes the question is invalid, Regarding further comments, No, You cannot use the definition you mentioned at last, Because the problem is not with $x=0$, The problem is with $f(x)=0$, So whenever $f(x)=0$, The logarithmic Functional equation is not defined, One way I think the question Can be modified is by Stating the function equation in exponential form, Which is $f(3x)=2^x\cdot3f(x)$

Comment: Are we getting $f(x)=0$ apart from when $x=0$?

Comment: @aarbee, From the latter function that we found ,no, But that does not matter, You defined $f(x)=0$ at $x=0$, Which itself again is out of the domain of original logarithmic functional equation, So as long as $f(x)=0$ even for one value of $x$, In your case, For $x=0$, The original functional equation in form of logarithm cannot be true for all real values of $x$, As it fails for $x=0$, Which is not what we want

Comment: Ya, if we restrict the functional equation to all $x$ except $0$ and define $f(0)$ separately then do you think the question statement would become valid?

Comment: Let $f$ be a differentiable function satisfying $\log_2(f(3x))=x+\log_2(3f(x))\;\forall x\in\mathbb R-\{0\}$ and $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$. Find the value of $[f(3)]$, where $[k]$ denotes greatest integer less than or equal to $k$.

Comment: How does this sound/read?

Comment: Just trying to see what minimum changes can be done to the question to make it valid.

Comment: @aarbee, Yes My bad, I didn't think you were implying to rule out $x=0$ from initial functional equation domain directly, It seems valid now

Answer (score 1):

The functional equation doesnt make much sense when $f(x)$ is negative. Whoever made the problem possibly inteded for us to solve
$$\frac{f(3x)}{3} = 2^x f(x) \ \ (♧)$$ over $x \in R$.
I shall proceed to solve this, and connect this on with the actual equation later.
Now, $f'(3x)=2^x(f'(x)+\ln2\cdot f(x))$. Since $f'(0)=1$, $f(0)=0$.
So $f(x)$ has a root at $x=0$. This means $f(x)=xg(x)$ for some $g(x)$. $$g(3x)=2^xg(x)$$
But $\exists t(x)$ s.t. $g(x)=2^\frac{x}{2} t(x)^{*}$
Hence, $t(3x)=t(x)$. Getting to this point is important because now we can solve the more familiar functional equation $f(3x)=f(x)$.

Let's consider $$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} 2^{h/2}t(h)=t(0)=1$$

Now, $t(x)=t(x/3)=t(x/27)=\dots=\lim_{n\to \infty} t(x/3^n) = t(0) \ \forall x\in R$. We conclude $t(x)=1$.

So the function you're looking for is $f(x)=x\cdot 2^{x/2}$.

Taking the logarithm of $(♧)$:
$$\log_2{f(3x)} = x + \log_2{f(x)} \ (♡)$$ where $f(3x),f(x)>0$. Hence $x>0$ is sufficient. The question says the equation $(♡)$ holds for all $x \in R$. But we now know that can't be possible -- it can only for $x \in R^{+}$.

Anyways: $f(3)= 6\cdot\sqrt 2 = 8.46$.

Note: $^*$ the reason why I substituted $g(x)=2^{x/2}t
(x)$ is because that would allow me to cancel the common factor of $2^{3/2}$ from both sides, giving a more familiar functional equation for a constant function.

Comment: Wonderful answer, thanks.